Since linear ODEs have a general solution, when are integrating factors needed?
Linear homogenous ODEs with constant coefficients have straightforward general solutions; common classes of inhomogeneous have general solutions as well.
Integrating factors are only useful for linear ODEs.  When do we need them? Why can't we just use the general solution of linear ODEs?
Are integrating factors only needed when the ODE does not have constant coefficients, so that the general linear ODE solution isn't applicable? Are there other cases where the general linear ODE solution isn't applicable, but integrating factors are?

Integrating factors are also useful for solving inexact differential equations, which can be nonlinear.

What about linear ODEs with variable coefficients?

Wherever did you get the idea that integrating factors were only useful for linear ODE's?
